# How can I do contract call transaction from Metamask qr code scan?

Tags: solidity, web3js, contract-development, metamask, etherscan

I have a payable function in the smart contract that takes some ether from the sender and does some tasks. I want to generate QR code for this contract call transaction so that user can scan and confirm from their Metamask mobile app. But I am not sure how to implement that.
We can generate qr code for general ether transfer transaction by the URL: 
`ethereum:0x7e3b984faE2b9235B38D8f8704091253F6e34692?value=1e18`

Similarly, can we generate the QR code for the contract calls from [EIP-681](https://brunobar79.github.io/eip681-link-generator/) and [eip681-link-generator](https://brunobar79.github.io/eip681-link-generator/). But the generated QR code is not working with metamask app.
So, can I generate the contract call QR code for metamask??

Comment: maybe you can check out https://github.com/jibrelnetwork/ethereum-qr-code/blob/master/README.md, looks like it is able to make a smart contract call into a qr code